# Rails app on two domain + nginx + passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

How can I have one app on two domains using nginx + passenger? I add second domain in nginx but this redirect to domain1.net

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain2.net *.domain2.net;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain2.net/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain2.net;
    root /var/www/domain1/public/;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!

}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain1.net *.domain1.net;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain1.net/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain1.net;
    root /var/www/domain1/public/;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
    passenger_enabled on;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location / {
        passenger_enabled on;
        root /var/www/domain1/public/; 

    }
}
```

What I want is to have one app on two domains because I want to translate app for users from second domain.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name domain2.net *.domain2.net;
     rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain2.net/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain2.net;
    root /var/www/domain1/public/;
    passenger_enabled on;
    location / {
      passenger_enabled on;
      root /var/www/domain1/public/; 
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.net *.domain1.net;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain1.net/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain1.net;
    root /var/www/domain1/public/;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
    passenger_enabled on;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location / {
      passenger_enabled on;
      root /var/www/domain1/public/; 
    }
}
```

you should add passenger stream also to the second domain then it should work.

One tip move each domain into site.conf file then include then in nginx.conf this will be easier to maintenance.

make sure you restart Nginx after the change.

Comment: Why not just do `server_name www.domain1.net www.domain2.net;` in the passenger-enabled server block?

Comment: this is also an option.